# Javascript in partial view in MVC2

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am using MVC2 in my project.I have this code in the ".aspx" page which determines if the ".ascx" page should be displayed:

```
<% if(Model.MRxECG != null) { %>
                     <div id="ecg">
                        <% Html.RenderPartial("ecgDetails", Model); %>
                    </div>
                     <% } %>
```

This is the code in ".ascx" page.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Intranet.Models.CareRecord.CareRecordSummaryModel>" %>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function resImage(image)
    {
        var resize = 200; // amount in percentage
        var oldheight  = 150;  // height of your image
        var oldwidth  = 250; // width of your image
        var X = event.x;
        var Y = event.y;
        var newHeight   = oldheight * (resize / 100);
        var newWidth   = oldwidth * (resize / 100);

        image.style.height = newHeight;//height of new image
        image.style.width  = newWidth;// width of new image

        var c = image.parentNode;

        c.scrollLeft = (X * (resize / 100)) - (newWidth / 2) / 2; //this is for 
        c.scrollTop  = (Y * (resize / 100)) - (newHeight / 2) / 2;//new center
}
    </script>

<div>
    <table class="layout" width="900px">
        <tr>
            <td>
             <img src='<%= Url.Action("ShowMRx12LeadImage", "CareRecord", new { id = Model.CareRecord.CaseNumber}) %>'
                                                        alt="12-Lead ECG" style="width: 1000px; height: 800px;" onmouseover="resImage(this)" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

The image doesn't zoom on mouseover event. I tried placing the Javascript code in the ".aspx" page but thata didnt work. What should I do to make this work?

I am not sure if Javascript works in the .ascx page.Do I have to ue jQuery to achieve the zoom-in functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `image.style.height` should be a string with specified dimension (px), not a number.

Consider changing these lines:

```
image.style.height = newHeight + 'px';//height of new image
image.style.width  = newWidth + 'px';// width of new image
```

There is a sample of `onmouseover`: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onmouseover, you can try here how it works.